# Drupal WSOD Error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, web, drupal-8

I've researched about settings.php, index.php, and .htaccess but to no avail.
Basically I want to back up my production site to my acquia dev desktop 2 site. Here I made a back up of the folder and database.

But when I try to load the website I get `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.` and in the console log I get:

```
GET https://omgyay.dd:8443/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)  favicon.ico:1

GET https://omgyay.dd:8443/ 500 (500 Service unavailable (with message))  omgyay.dd/:1
Navigated to https://omgyay.dd:8443
```

and inside the apache log I get `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.'`

Any information is helpful. Mostly on how to print out the specific error message. Again, this error message is after I migrated my code over locally and before I can see any webpages once installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case php7.0-crul missing.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-crul

service apache2 restart
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my question. Basically The GET error had nothing to do with the error itself, but the Apache log was very informative.

You can find the log by clicking on Acquia Dev Desktop on the top left > preferences > Logs > Apache errors. Then it opens up a .txt and scroll all the way to the bottom. It told me I had no access to the database.

I had the wrong username and password to my database in Settings.php and changed them.